# Crear punto de acceso con un router

Tags: router

yo quiero hacer un punto de acceso mediante un router para permita mostrar una pagina que ya tengo y que puedan interactuar y reenvie esa informacion a un equipo. si pudieran aportar con guias o foros sobre el tema. Gracias

Comment: Cuál es la dificultad que estás enfrentando?

Comment: es que desconosco como hacerlo y busco informacion no consigo

Comment: Necesitas aclarar algunas cosas: Se trata de un acceso dentro de la misma intranet (computadoras conectadas, por ejemplo, a la red de tu casa, puedan ver el sitio) o de otro modo, por ejemplo, querés que se pueda acceder a una página en la computadora de tu casa desde internet? También es necesario saber con que sistema operativo corrés el servidor web y qué servidor web estás usando. Esta información por favor agregala a la pregunta editando la misma, no como comentarios abajo porque son más difíciles de leer.